# Is this grammatically valid? Or Should I separate the two sentences and rid the semicolon

Tags: grammar

Is this grammatically valid? Or Should I separate the two sentences and rid the semicolon

> When a parent is passionate about something, they may often pressure their children; the pressure causes the kids to do whatever it is the parents want, just to simply please them.

Answer (score 1):

This is grammatically valid. However, I think it would be stronger and better writing if split into two sentences. But it would not be more grammatical.